# How can We make Dynamic array using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have an array  Which holds

```
<type 'list'>: [u'189,297', u'204,448', u'205,297',u'304,448',u'122,297', u'224,448']
```

Desire result

```
list1
[u'203,448',  u'204,448', u'230,448',, u'24,448', ]

list2
<type 'list'>: [ u'204,297',  u'205,297', u'231,297', u'24,297']
```

And I want to Separately split  features  OF 297 and 448    In 2 different array or 2 list 
Thanks In advance

Comment: How is the output related to the input? E.g. where does `'203'` come from?

Comment: there are 2 list is js 
I merge them so i can identify Them in back end
So i merge 
203 ,448 
204 ,297

Comment: Hmm... I see one list that you call input and `'203'` is not in it. How is anybody supposed to help you there?

Comment: You have to post the question with full input material and desired output. as @schwobaseggl pointed out from where `203` `230` coming from , .

Comment: Ok @AyodhyankitPaul

Answer (score -1):

you can try with the "split" method:

```
import numpy as np
v =['189,297', '204,448', '205,297','304,448','122,297', '224,448']

m = np.zeros((len(v),2))

for i in range(len(v)):
    m[i,:] = v[i].split(",") 

m
array([[ 189.,  297.],
   [ 204.,  448.],
   [ 205.,  297.],
   [ 304.,  448.],
   [ 122.,  297.],
   [ 224.,  448.]])
```